# UISlider value Convert float to percentage

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a label that shows UIImaveView's alpha value , I need to declare a percentage value that show 0 to 100% . here is my code :

```
- (IBAction)changeAlpha:(id)sender {

    _view3D.alpha  = _slider.value;

    _lableP.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",_slider.value *100];
}
```

but the result :

```
2014-03-04 16:50:35.676 App[3743:70b] 91.176468  
2014-03-04 16:50:35.753 App[3743:70b] 90.000000
2014-03-04 16:50:35.782 App[3743:70b] 88.235298
```

that's not a number still a float number , how can I show numbers like these :

91%
90%
20%

thanks .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 _lableP.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",_slider.value *100];
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple: use `@"%.f"` instead of `@"%f"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:slider.value];
NSInteger myInt = [myNumber intValue];
```

Comment: `NSInteger myInt = slider.value;` will be easier :)